# $f$ monic polynomial over ring $R$. $R[x]/(f)\otimes_R A\cong A[x]/(f)$ where $A$ is any $R$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be a monic polynomial over unital ring $R$. Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra.

Consider product map $R[x]/(f)\otimes_R A\to A[x]/(f)$. It is clear that this map is surjection. However, I am not fully convinced the map is injection.(Since $f$ is monic, $R[x]/(f)$ is a free $R$ module and similarly for $A[x]/(f)$ as free $A$-module. The morphism on both sides are identifying the $A$-module level map. However, I would like to say this is $R$-algebra as well.)

$\textbf{Q1:}$ Is there a good reason $R[x]/(f)\otimes_R A\to A[x]/(f)$ being isomorphism?

Comment: Q1: Extension of scalars. This is what tensor products are good for among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following exact sequence of $R$-modules:
$$\{0\}\to\langle f\rangle\to R[x]\to R[x]/\langle f\rangle\to\{0\}$$
By tensoring with $A$ we get the following commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R[x]f\otimes_RA @>>>
R[x]\otimes_RA @>>>
R[x]/\langle f\rangle\otimes_RA @>>>
\{0\}\\
@VVV @VVV @| \\
A[x]f @>>>
A[x] @>>>
R[x]/\langle f\rangle\otimes_RA @>>>
\{0\}
\end{CD}$$
where the middle vertical arrow is an isomorphisms while the left-handed vertical arrow is surjective.
This proves that the kernel of the surjective $R$-algebra homomorphism $A[x]\to R[x]/\langle f\rangle\otimes_RA$ is $A[x]f$.